# Ignore rule for specific file in editorconfig

Tags: android, editorconfig

I want to disable the rule for a specific file.
Have file `.editorconfig` in my project with next configuration:

```
# http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[src/main/java/com/mandarine/targetList/interfaces/OnBackPressListenerEEE.kt]
disabled-rules = filename
```

But also get error for my class:

> /home/vadimm/AndroidStudioProjects/target-list/app/src/main/java/com/mandarine/targetList/interfaces/OnBackPressListenerEEE.kt:1:1: interface OnBackPressListener should be declared in a file named OnBackPressListener.kt (cannot be auto-corrected)

What am I doing wrong?